# Failed calling ITaskScheduler::Activate

Tags: winapi, com

I want to get the Windows Schedule Task infomation. I copied this code from MSDN [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/c-c-code-example-starting-a-task).

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Call ITaskScheduler::Activate to get the Task object.
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  ITask *pITask;
  LPCWSTR lpcwszTaskName;
  lpcwszTaskName = L"Test Task";
  hr = pITS->Activate(lpcwszTaskName,
                      IID_ITask,
                      (IUnknown**) &pITask);

  pITS->Release();
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
     wprintf(L"Failed calling ITaskScheduler::Activate; error = 0x%x\n",hr);
     CoUninitialize();
     return 1;
  }
```

It works very well on my Win10 X64 computer. But it fails on another Win7 X86 computer.
When I use Remote Debugger, the error code is `0x80070002`. VS debugger tells me it means `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. But I go to the definition of ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
#define ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND             2L
```

It's a different code.

And When I run the program directly on the Win7 x86 computer. It gave me another error code

```
0x8007007b
```

I can't find the meaning.
So I don't know why the calling fails on the Win7 computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0x80070002` equals `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`, so it means the same as `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

`0x8007007b` equals `HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INVALID_NAME)`.

So both error codes seem to indicate that the task you are looking for doesn't exist.

In the future, when you see an error code starting with `0x8` it most likely is a [`HRESULT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) value. Dissecting the `HRESULT` code as described by Wikipedia gives:

- Bit `0x80000000` means failure.
- We have a facility value of 7 (`(hr & 0x07FF0000 ) >> 16`) which means Win32 error
- The lower 16 bits (`hr & 0xFFFF` -> `0x0002` and `0x007b` in these cases) are the actual error value which you can look up in the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes).

Firegiant provides a [nice web service](http://errco.de/) for directly looking up `HRESULT` values and other kinds of error codes.

Comment: Actually, I changed another way to get the task time. The document says this method is old.